# elasticsearch distinct parent sub aggregation without nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch 6.2 I have a parent-child relationship :

```
Document -> NamedEntity
```

I want to aggregate NamedEntity by counting `mention` field **and** giving the number of documents that contains each named entity.

My use case is :

```
doc1 contains 'NER'(_id=ner11), 'NER'(_id=ner12)
doc2 contains 'NER'(_id=ner2)
```

The parent/child relation is implemented with [a join field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/parent-join.html). In the `Document` I have a field :

```
join: {
  name: "Document"
}
```

And in the `NamedEntity` children :

```
join: {
  name: "NamedEntity",
  parent: "parent_id"
}
```

with `_routing` set to `parent_id`.

So I tried with terms sub-aggregation :

```
curl -XPOST elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{"query":{"term":{"type":"NamedEntity"}},
 "aggs":{
   "mentions":{
     "terms":{
       "field":"mention"
     },
     "aggs":{
       "docs":{
         "terms":{"field":"join"}
       }
     }
   }
 }
}'
```

And I have the following response :

```
"aggregations" : {
  "mentions" : {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "NER",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "docs" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "NamedEntity",
              "doc_count" : 3 <-- WRONG ! There are 2 distinct documents
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I find the expected **3 occurrences** in `mentions.buckets.doc_count`. But in the `mentions.buckets.docs.buckets.doc_count` field **I would like** to have only **2 documents** (not 3). Like a `select count distinct`.

If I aggregate with `"terms":{"field":"join.parent"}` I have :

```
...
"docs" : {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
    "buckets" : [ ]
}
...
```

I tied with `cardinality` aggregation on the `join` field and I obtain a value of 1, and `cardinality` aggregation on the `join.parent` that returns a value of 0.

So how do you make an aggregation distinct count on parents without the use of a [reverse nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) ?

---

As @AndreiStefan asked, here is the mapping. It is a simple 1-N relation between `Document(content)` and `NamedEntity(mention)` in an ES 6 mapping (fields are defined on the same level) :

```
curl -XPUT elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
    "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "index_options": "offsets"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "join": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "Document": "NamedEntity"
          }
        },
        "mention": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
}}
```

And the requests for a minimal dataset :

```
curl -XPUT elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs/doc/doc1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type": "Document", "join": {"name": "Document"}, "content": "a NER document contains 2 NER"}'
curl -XPUT elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs/doc/doc2 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type": "Document", "join": {"name": "Document"}, "content": "another NER document"}'
curl -XPUT elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs/doc/ner11?routing=doc1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type": "NamedEntity", "join": {"name": "NamedEntity", "parent": "doc1"}, "mention": "NER"}'
curl -XPUT elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs/doc/ner12?routing=doc1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type": "NamedEntity", "join": {"name": "NamedEntity", "parent": "doc1"}, "mention": "NER"}'
curl -XPUT elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs/doc/ner2?routing=doc2 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type": "NamedEntity", "join": {"name": "NamedEntity", "parent": "doc2"}, "mention": "NER"}'
```

Comment: Can you add a more easy to test set of data? For someone who wants to help but doesn't have much time at his disposal to untangle what you are trying to do, some test documents, mappings for the relevant fields and a search query that doesn't work will help. You provided the query, but I didn't understand from your examples what you are trying to achieve, nor I see some sample documents or complete mappings for things like `mentionNorm`...

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks for your comment. The dataset is rather small a doc A has a list of children B and I wanted to avoid a very long question with mappings. But you're right mentionNorm is noisy and I'll try to add some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  "aggs": {
    "mentions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mention"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "join"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "uniques": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "join#Document"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

OR if you just want the count:

```
  "aggs": {
    "mentions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mention"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "uniques": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "join#Document"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you need a custom ordering (by unique counts):

```
  "aggs": {
    "mentions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mention",
        "order": {
          "uniques": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "uniques": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "join#Document"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank  you @AndreiStephan. A subsidiary question : do you know how I could make the results ordered by the uniques first ?

Comment: I mean the order is by #mentions. If ne1 has 6 mentions in 2 docs and ne2 has 4 mentions in 4 docs, I'd like to see ne2 first.

Comment: I've seen that it breaks the order desc on count so I made "order": [{ "uniques": "desc" }, {"_count": "desc"}]

Answer (score 1):

I post this workaround in case it can help someone. But if someone has a cleaner way of doing this, I'd be interested.

I added a denormalized field in the children that contains a copy of the parent id (the value already in `join/parent`):

```
curl -XPUT elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
    "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "index_options": "offsets"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "join": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "Document": "NamedEntity"
          }
        },
        "document_id: {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "mention": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
}}
```

Then the cardinality aggregate with this new field works as expected :

```
curl -XPOST elasticsearch:9200/datashare-testjs/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{"query":{"term":{"type":"NamedEntity"}},
 "aggs":{
   "mentions":{
     "terms":{
       "field":"mention"
     },
     "aggs":{
       "docs":{
         "cardinality": {
           "field" : "document_id"
       }
     }
   }
}}}'
```

It responds :

```
...
"aggregations" : {
  "mentions" : {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "NER",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "docs" : {
          "value" : 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue on Elasticsearch 7.1, and this additional field "my_join_field#my_parent" created by elasicsearch solved it. I am glad I didn't have to add the parent_id to the child document.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_searching_with_parent_join